# How to push a file inside a folder made in a github repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, cs50

I know how to create a folder in a GitHub repository using web interface but how do i make sure that i push a file in a specific folder given that there are many folders in my repository?

I'm using the cs50 online ide.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are solely using Github Web Interface to upload file in a folder of your repository. If that's the case, you should go to your repository and then go into the folder you want to create file in and follow instructions given in their documentation:

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository/

> 1. Under your repository name, click Upload files.
> 2. Drag and drop the file or folder you'd like to upload to your repository onto the file tree.
> 3. At the bottom of the page, type a short, meaningful commit message that describes the change you made to the file.
> 4. Below the commit message fields, decide whether to add your commit to the current branch or to a new branch. If your current branch is master, you should choose to create a new branch for your commit and then create a pull request.
> 5. Click Commit changes.

#### Edit:

Using git commands:

```
git clone <repository_link> #(Https/SSH)
# make required changes to this cloned local repository
git add --all # stage all the changes
git commit -m 'your commit message' # commit into the repository
git push <origin> <branch> # push to the remote repository

# To list available upstreams of this repository <origin>:
git remote -v
# To see branch you are on:
git branch
```

Comment: ok, let me edit my answer, did you have repo on your local computer too?
If not then you will be needing to clone it.

Comment: No I don't.. by local computer we mean the online ide right?

Comment: No I have not pushed anything into the repo yet but I have made my project .. in the ide consisting of different folders

Comment: Does your Online IDE provide Git support? or you have SSH or Any Other kind of access into that online machine you are working on?

Comment: Or can you share link of the IDE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130339/discussion-between-qubad-and-kartikeykant18).

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repo locally, make sure you add the file in the folder you want then push.

Comment: that is my question actually how do i add the file in the folder, is there a git command?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `git fetch` command before pushing.